# is the set of all sequences that converge to zero first category

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

the metric space is: the set of all convergent sequences with metric supremum.
the subset is: all sequences that converge to zero.

is the subset first category in this metric space?

we have figured out that the subset is closed and it is rare (nowhere dense), but does this suffice that it is first category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is first category (meager) if it can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets.  So if your set is nowhere dense, then it is automatically first category ($A = A \cup A \cup A \cup \cdots$ or $A = A \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \cdots$).